# Что такое абсолютный ассемблер?

Tags: ассемблер

Что такое абсолютный ассемблер? Если это возможно, скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на пример программы на абсолютном ассемблере для одноадресной машины.

Comment: С такими просьбами  вы лет на 80 опоздали. Уже давным-давно ассемблеры (и компиляторы) производят объектники в том или ином relocatable формате, который может быть превращен в форму с абсолютными адресами программой, которую называют *линкер*